# iOS: Flip whole app UI for Arabic & Hebrew like languages programmatically without storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

I am designing my whole app UI programmatically without using Storyboard.
My application requirement is to flip whole app with the localised language.

I can achieve this by applying transformation on each and every elements.
But for whole app it is becoming complex.

extension for flipping elements :

```
extension CGAffineTransform {
    static func uiTransform() -> CGAffineTransform {
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "i18n_language") == "ar" {
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
            return transform
        }else{
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            return transform
        }
    }
}
```

extension call :

```
self.MasterView.transform = CGAffineTransform.uiTransform()
```

I tried to apply semanticContentAttribute but it is not working properly.

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

[image: Screen shot 1]

[image: Screen shot 2]

Can anybody suggest that, how can I perform flipping more adaptively for whole app?

Comment: dont use this         `self.MasterView.transform = CGAffineTransform.uiTransform()`

Comment: without using it please upload a screen shot

Comment: As long as you use autolayout with `leading` and `trailing` constraints RTL will be handled correctly. If you aren't using autolayout, use autolayout.

Comment: I am not using storyboard at all.

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I have uploaded 2 screen shots please refer ...

Comment: Please guide me in understanding your question. You want to change the text alignment of label if its arabic?

Comment: @RahulDasgupta...not only text alignment...for Arabic we also need to flip whole layout in the opposite direction. How it can be handled for all screens in the app.

Comment: As @Paulw11 said if you use AutoLayout and pin your elements using `leading` and `trailing` constraints your UI will be flipped when needed. If you are **NOT** using AutoLayout, drop everything and start using it. It will make your life a lot easier. And you don't need to use storyboards to use AutoLayout.

Comment: @MihaiFratu...at first thanks for your response but...It is not possible for me to drop everything and start using it because it is a product based app and can't change everything at once. Is there any other way...?

Comment: There is no easy way.  There are a lot of benefits that come with autolayout; RTL localisation is one of them.  If you aren't using autolayout then you are going to have to address each UI element individually.  I suspect you will spend more time doing this than switching to autolayout

Answer (score 0):

It's best to do the auto layout for this. Usually, While creating Auto Layout constraints programmatically used to be tedious, there are several excellent open source frameworks that provide a Domain-Specific Language (DSL) for easily creating Auto Layout constraints in Swift code.

One of which I can suggest is TinyConstraints: https://github.com/roberthein/TinyConstraints.
Try it out.